# How do you unit test unique method calls in Jasmine/Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, jasmine

I have code in my application where a certain function is called n-times (lets call this function `foo`). The runtime expectation is that each invocation of `foo` is **unique** (called with a unique set of arguments). I had a recent bug manifest in my app due to `foo` being called with the same set of arguments more than once.

I want to write a test case where I can assert that `foo` was uniquely called once with a specific set of args but I'm at a loss at how to do so in Jasmine/Jest.

I know Jasmine has the `toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith` matcher but that asserts that `foo` was called "exactly once, and exactly with the particular arguments" which is not what I'm looking for in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `toHaveBeenCalledWith()` and `toHaveBeenCalledTimes()` to get your desired behaivor, you just need to have as many `toHaveBeenCalledWith()`s as the number of calls you were expecting:

for ex:

```
describe("test", () => {
  it("should call not more than unique", () => {
     spyOn(callsFoo, 'foo');
     callsFoo.somethingThatCallsFoo();
     expect(callsFoo.foo).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
     expect(callsFoo.foo).toHaveBeenCalledWith({...someArgs});
     expect(callsFoo.foo).toHaveBeenCalledWith({...otherUnique});
  });
})
```

This would fail if there were repeated calls that weren't unique.

Comment: Ah, I see! This works great! I suppose I'll have to add all the discrete call assertions.