# Property 'toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith' does not exist on type 'JestMatchers<Mock<any, any>>'

Tags: javascript, angular, jestjs

I have added 3 JSON files as dynamic configuration, so these files will be loaded when the app is initialized.

After migrating my Jasmine-Karma code to Jest, I am facing this issue :

```
Property 'toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith' does not exist on type 'JestMatchers<Mock<any, any>>'.
```

in app.module.ts

```
export function configLoader(injector: Injector) : () => Promise<any>
{
    return () => injector.get(ConfigurationService).loadConfiguration();
}
export function configProdLoader(injector: Injector) : () => Promise<any> {
    return () => injector.get(ConfigurationService).loadProdConfig();
}

export function configEnvironmentLoader(injector: Injector) : () => Promise<any>
{
    return () => injector.get(ConfigurationService).loadEnvironmentConfig();
}
```

App module provides

```
 {provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: configLoader, deps: [Injector], multi: true},
        {provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: configProdLoader, deps: [Injector], multi: true},
        {provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: configEnvironmentLoader, deps: [Injector], multi: true},
```

My test.spec.ts

```
describe("ConfigurationService", () => {

    const returnValue = {};

    let httpMock: {get: jest.Mock};

    let service: ConfigurationService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        httpMock = {
            get: jest.fn(() => of(returnValue)),
        };

        service = new ConfigurationService(<any>httpMock);
    });

    test('Should call the endpoint and retrieve the config', (done) => {
        service.loadConfiguration().then(() => {
            expect(httpMock.get)
                .toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith(service['configPath']);
            expect(service['configData']).toBe(returnValue);
            done();
        });
    });

    test('Should call the endpoint and retrieve the configProd', (done) => {
        service.loadProdConfig().then(() => {
            expect(httpMock.get)
                .toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith(service['configProdPath']);
            expect(service['configProdData']).toBe(returnValue);
            done();
        });
    });

    test('Should call the endpoint and retrieve the configEnvironment', (done) => {
        service.loadEnvironmentConfig().then(() => {
            expect(httpMock.get)
                .toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith(service['configEnvironmentPath']);
            expect(service['configEnvironmentData']).toBe(returnValue);
            done();
        });
    });


});
```

my service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConfigurationService {
    private configData: any | undefined;
    private configProdData: any | undefined;
    private configEnvironmentData: any | undefined;
    private readonly configPath: string = '../../assets/config/aws-config.json';
    private readonly configProdPath: string = '../../assets/config/prod-config.json';
    private readonly configEnvironmentPath: string = '../../assets/config/environment-config.json';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

    async loadConfiguration(): Promise<any> {
        try {
            const response = await this.httpClient.get(`${this.configPath}`)
                .toPromise().then(res => this.configData = res);
            return this.configData;
        } catch (err) {
            return Promise.reject(err);
        }
    }

    get config(): any | undefined {
        return this.configData;
    }

    async loadProdConfig(): Promise<any> {
        try {
            const response = await this.httpClient.get(`${this.configProdPath}`)
                .toPromise().then(res => this.configProdData = res);
            return this.configProdData;
        } catch (err) {
            return Promise.reject(err);
        }
    }

    get configProd(): any | undefined {
        return this.configProdData;
    }

    async loadEnvironmentConfig(): Promise<any> {
        try {
            const response = await this.httpClient.get(`${this.configEnvironmentPath}`)
                .toPromise().then(res => this.configEnvironmentData = res);
            return this.configEnvironmentData;
        } catch (err) {
            return Promise.reject(err);
        }
    }

    get configEnvironmentProd(): any | undefined {
        return this.configEnvironmentData;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong in tests?

Comment: That's indeed _not_ a matcher in Jest - it's not listed in https://jestjs.io/docs/expect.

Comment: then how to fix it?

Comment: Use matchers that _do_ exist? See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/69302869/3001761.

Comment: lol.. you also had another option to create a custom matcher that does what you want. https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#custom-matchers-api

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who found this because they are using `aws-sdk-client-mock`...

You need to import the jest matchers that come with `aws-sdk-client-mock`[1].

`import 'aws-sdk-client-mock-jest';`

I suspect you are missing an import of the definition of these custom matchers too.

1. https://github.com/m-radzikowski/aws-sdk-client-mock#jest-matchers

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing `jest-extended` in your types. Add this to your `global.d.ts` file or in the specific test file that fails:

```
/// <reference types="jest-extended" />
```